Staging Ground "Guide" badge missing from profile's badges list
The new Staging Ground badge "Guide" does not appear to be selectable or visible at all in the profile's badge picker/tracker UI. I have not earned this badge yet, but it is not appearing when I filter for it:

And if I type in "Guide" and filter by "All", there are no results:


N.B. I have since earned the badge, and it shows up on my profile, but it still doesn't appear in this tracker modal UI anywhere, whether as 'earned' or 'eligible'.

Thank you for reporting this issue! We originally didn't implement the "Guide" badge as a trackable one, which is why you didn't see it in the badge tracking section in your profile. We just updated the badge to be trackable. You can now track it like other trackable badges.

This is not fixed yet on the mobile view at least; I still can't find it (even as an earned badge) when opening the modal and scrolling through the "All" list. I won't be able to test on a desktop view for several more days.

@TylerH That's odd, because I can see the badges on the mobile view. Are you looking at your profile on Meta StackOverflow by any chance? The badges are only enabled on Stackoverflow.com.

I confirm that I can see it on Tyler's profile on mobile: https://i.sstatic.net/gwfnQaZI.png

@RyanM That's not the view I was talking about. I was talking about the tracker at the top of the summary page, when you expand it to view badges available for earning (or already earned, when sorted by All).

I can confirm the Guide badge is now shown in the All list of that modal and as having been earned, though I obviously can't confirm it is fixed for those who haven't earned it yet... must have just been a delayed rollout when I checked on the 18th.
